# How to import a CSS in a scoped style with Marp?

Tags: css, markdown, marp

Using Marp, is there a way to import a scoped CSS theme without overwriting the global style?

For example, when I use this snippet overwrites the global style

```
---
<style scoped>
@import url('custom-theme-scoped.css');
</style>
# Section 1
---
```

Note: The content of `custom-theme-scoped.css` is

```
h2 {
  color: orange;
}
```

---

However, using the following snippet works correctly and overwrites only the current section

```
---
<style scoped>
h2 {
  color: orange;
}
</style>
# Section 1
---
```

Answer (score -1):

When using Marp, the scoped CSS style is designed to only apply to the current slide and its descendants. However, Marp doesn't support the direct import of an external CSS file into a scoped style tag without affecting the global styles.

If you want to import a scoped CSS theme without overwriting the global style, you can achieve it by manually copying the styles from the external CSS file into the scoped style tag. Here's an example:

```
---
<style scoped>
/* Manually copy the styles from custom-theme-scoped.css here */
h2 {
  color: orange;
}
</style>
# Section 1
```

By copying the styles into the scoped style tag, you ensure that they are only applied to the current slide and its descendants, without affecting the global styles.

Note: This approach requires manually maintaining the styles in both the external CSS file and the scoped style tag. If you make changes to the external CSS file, you'll need to update the scoped style tag accordingly.

`Important Note: This answer is generated by Chat-GPT`

You can also check this solution to apply some styles on scoped [Support  to apply inline style to current page](https://github.com/marp-team/marpit/issues/85)

Comment: Once I read: Here's an example: and found the example that I've already added for what works inside the question I was certain that ChatGPT was being used.
I totally respect your effort for asking ChatGPT for an answer, and I'm also glad that clearly cited it, however this answer is only polluting the site, as the question already states the discrepancy that the answer is repeating ... this answer could be reducing entropy if it would cite where is it mentioned that imports are not supported in the scoped styles.

Comment: @weshouman imports are allowed but it will override the global/previous styles

Comment: you're just contradicting the answer that you pasted from ChatGPT which states that Marp doesn't support **the direct import of an external CSS file into a scoped style tag without affecting the global styles.** Which means that the global style would be affected not just overriden for the current section

Comment: @weshouman according to marp documentation here https://marpit.marp.app/theme-css `@import` doesn't need url() function. if this help you I out then revert back I will modify the answer removing Chat-GPT response. With this reference, otherwise you can ask me to remove this answer

Comment: @MijanurRahaman, unfortunately that does not answer the question. As the question is about the scoped styling of specific slides not changing the whole theme. FYI, sharing a section of the documentation is more beneficial (by copying the link of the section's title), unless you really meant sharing the whole page.